# Power dissipation of MOSFET with PWM and current regulation

Tags: mosfet, pwm, led-driver, current-limiting, thermal

I don't understand the formula for the thermal dissipation of the STCS1A. The [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stcs1a.pdf) in chapter 8.2 states:

```
Pd = (Vd - Vfb) * Id + (Vcc * Icc)
```

Where `Vd` is `Vcc - VLED`.
Here the connection scheme:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKqQuc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the MOSFET turns on, the current flows through the LEDs and the feedback resistor. Internally, the feedback voltage is fed to a comparator that turns off the MOSFET when the preset current is reached.

Now, while the MOSFET is on, the voltage across the diodes depends on their forward voltage with the actual current. The voltage across the MOSFET is due to the Rds_on (ideally it would be a short-circuit) so it also *fixed* by the current. The only component that would receive the remaining voltage is the feedback resistor.

Of course, at steady-state this would be `Vcc - VLED - Vds` but this is never reached because the MOSFET is turned off when the Vfb is ~ 100 mV in order to achieve the current regulation.

If this is correct, **I don't understand why the voltage across drain-source receive the gap between VLED and Vcc**. *The MOSFET is not used in the linear region*, it's a PWM control so it's off or completely on.

If I'm wrong and the datasheet is correct (and I bet that's right!) it means that if you use a high voltage supply with few LEDs, the MOSFET will dissipate a lot more. But this makes no sense to me. I selected this device because I understood it regulates the current turning off the MOSFET whenever the current rises over the preselected value, so the power dissipation (during the on-state) would be just `Vds * Id` where `Vds = Rds_on * Id`.

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. The first term in the power equation are the MOSFET losses (VDS*Id) and the second term is the power drawn from the other pin that is connected to 24V

Comment: The question is: why the `Vds` in the MOSFET losses is calculated as `(Vcc-Vled-VRfb)`, instead of `Rds_on * Id`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this device is not, strictly speaking, using PWM to control LED current. There *is* a PWM input, but this never causes the MOSFET to be *completely on*, as I will explain.

You say that the feedback resistor "receives the remaining voltage", but that's not true. It is a current sense resistor, and this IC's function, as explained on page 10, section 7.1, is to maintain the voltage across it at exactly 100mV. This resistor is not there to drop any excess voltage, its purpose is only to sense current. In fact, it is the *MOSFET's job* to "drop" that excess voltage.

When the MOSFET is "on", it is only "on" enough to pass exactly enough current to achieve \$V_{FB} = 100mV\$. That is, it has exactly  the right \$R_{DS}\$ to drop exactly the right \$V_{DS}\$ so that \$V_{FB} = +100mV\$.

In other words, whenever the LEDs are lit, this device is operating as a *linear* current regulator, not PWM. The MOSFET is never fully on, always operating in its linear region.

This means that when the LEDs are lit, the MOSFET channel is dropping \$24V - 4V - 4V - 0.1V = 15.9V\$, as shown below. \$V_{DS}\$ is not zero (or even close), as you seem to have assumed. However, when the LEDs are dark, the MOSFET is completely off too.

The PWM input is only used to switch between modes "off" and "linear current regulation", and doesn't ever cause the MOSFET to turn completely on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzcIbI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the power dissipated in the device, while the LEDs are lit, is the sum of power used by the internal control circuitry, and power dissipated by the MOSFET while it linearly regulates LED current:

$$ P = \overbrace{\left[V_{CC}\times I_{CC}\right]}^\text{Control} + \overbrace{\left[(V_{DRAIN} - V_{FB}) \times I_D\right]}^\text{MOSFET} $$

Comment: It makes sense. I was confused about the "chopping" circuit (quite similar) used for example in stepper drivers. But there, the load is highly inductive and the voltage on the sense resistor rises with some delay, allowing the controller to turn on the mosfet completely and to turn it off as the voltage exceed the threshold. Here the situation is different, I see.

Answer (score 0):

The first contribution to Pd is the power wasted as heat by the MOSFET.

The second contribution to Pd is the power wasted as heat by the led controller.

The led controller and the MOSFET are on the same chip so Pd has two contributions.

The definition of power consumption of a MOSFET is:

Pd(t) = Id(t) * Vds(t)

or

Pd(t) = Rds(t) * Id(t) * Id(t)

In a lab it's much easier to use the first formula because you can measure currents and voltages.

Comment: Exactly, but Rds is a characteristic of the MOSFET. We don't know its value here, anyway we can assume it quite constant when the MOSFET is fully on. Hence, Vds depends on the current only. Instead, if you define Vds as (Vcc-Vled-Vrfb) it depends on the gap between the power supply rail and the voltage across the LEDs.

Comment: Rds is the ratio between two measurable variables: Vds and Ids.