# Difference between analog dimming and digital dimming an LED

Tags: voltage, led, current, led-driver, dimming

I would like to understand the difference between analog dimming and digital dimming in LED drivers.

I went through this [article](https://www.ti.com/lit/wp/sliy007/sliy007.pdf?ts=1678871766292&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) where there is some difference indication on page 4, but I'm still not able to get total clarity on this.

As far as I understand, both ADIM and DIM control the output forward current of the LED. DIM can do it with PWM, where ADIM needs a voltage within a specific range.

I find it difficult to understand what the differences are that one can obtain using ADIM and DIM.

Also, is it OK if I don't drive an LED on the output side, but some other load - say, some resistive load with constant current?

This is the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005462B.pdf) to an LED driver chip that has PWM and ADIM pins as inputs.

Comment: "page 4" The article continues the discussion on the next two pages, with fig 9 giving an illustration of dimming by varying the duty cycle of a PWM signal. Perhaps you could be more specific about what you are having difficulties understanding? Currently your question seems to be inviting us to write a full essay comparing analogue and digital LED control.

Comment: Have a watch of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zU2Oxyfi2Q4

Comment: "is it OK if I don't drive an LED on the output side" The LEDs respond to the current flowing through them. They don't care where it comes from. Note in fig 7 of the article the current in the left hand column of LEDs is controlled by sensing the voltage developed across the resistor at the bottom of the column. However your second question is rather vague. Can you add a circuit diagram to show what you are proposing?

Comment: @GrahamNye, I am just trying to connect a load resistor between the inductor and ground from the application circuit shown in the datasheet.

Comment: @GrahamNye, I did not understand your answer to my question of, "is it OK if I don't drive an LED on the output side". Could you please clarify a little more simpler, please?

Comment: Which figure is that? I can't see one that shows an inductor.

Comment: @GrahamNye, the second figure on page 2 of the datasheet.

Comment: What datasheet? Page 2 of the one you linked to has no diagrams.

Comment: "is it OK" Your supplementary question is too vague for me to answer. You're asking us "Can I drive my LEDs in some other way?" Well, perhaps you can and perhaps you can't. We need to see the details of your proposal to be able to comment. The usual way to show the details is with a circuit diagram (possibly as a high level block view). You should only ask one question at a time so this supplementary question would be better removed from this question and posted as a separate question, along with a diagram of your proposal.

Comment: Or you could provide a link to the datasheet you mentioned, as that seems to be different to the article you posted. Note that you have a close flag for posting a two part question so you should move the second part sooner rather than later.

Comment: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20005462B.pdf - @GrahamNye. This is the datasheet

Comment: The LEDs are already the load in that circuit. Connecting a resistor from ground to either side of the inductor won't have any useful results. So in this case it's not OK. (Please add the datasheet link to your question, rather than as a comment.)

Answer (score 4):

According to the HV9919B datasheet both inputs (DIM, ADIM) will create a PWM signal to the LEDs. The difference is that for the chip's DIM input you would be suppling your own PWM signal. If using the ADIM input you would provide a DC voltage from 0~2.0V and the chip would create an internal PWM signal related to the input voltage level. So in this case using ADIM just simulates analog dimming by using an analog input voltage.

The ADIM and V_ADIM listed in the article (page 6, Fig. 8) refer to true analog dimming with a simple variable DC current, (no PWM). The article notes that analog dimming is popular with camera related applications since there will be no flickering of the light.  LEDs that use PWM for dimming could be seen as flickering in a video due to the camera shutter speed catching the LEDs sometimes on and sometimes off.

If you were to drive a resistive load rather than LEDs the driver chip would likely operate about the same. (In which case you could say that you have a PWM resistive heater.)

.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In which cases, like in terms of which application, one should prefer ADIM over DIM and vice-versa?

Comment: @Newbie,   If using the PWM input you would need additional circuitry to create the variable pulse signal. This would allow very precise control if that were needed. If using the ADIM input you would just need to supply a DC reference voltage possibly from a potentiometer (or two resistors) to set the dimming level.

Answer (score 4):

When controlling current through some load, like LEDs, we almost always use a transistor, but the manner in which that transistor is employed is different between digital and analogue current control. Consider that we have a transistor (a MOSFET in my example here, but it can be a bipolar junction transistor, or BJT, the same principle applies), and it is placed in the path of current flow through some LEDs, between the terminals of a voltage source:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fE6AIx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transistor is under control of what current flows around the loop, and we have a choice about how we use it. We can use it as a switch (above centre), either open or closed, fully conductive or completely "off", just like a mechanical switch. There are no in-between states, just on and off, and this would be "digital control".

We may also choose to use the transistor with more granular control over how well it conducts (above right), making it behave like a variable resistance, and using that property to control how much current flows around the loop. This would be "analogue control". You might notice that we dispense with the current limiting resistor in that design, because the transistor takes on this role.

To understand why *analogue* control can be problematic, and why digital control may be preferred in some circumstances, we must examine the power dissipated by the transistor while it's doing it's job of being a "resistor". To alter the effective resistance of the transistor, we control the potential at its gate (or current into the base, if it's a BJT). The following circuit is grossly oversimplified, for illustration only:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZJ2a5.png)</sup>

I've set gate potential to +4.3V. A higher potential there would make the transistor more conductive, and vice versa. It's really sensitive, and pretty arbitrary, an issue too deep and complex to address here. For now just accept that our transistor has exactly the right resistance necessary to pass 231mA of current.

We can calculate the equivalent resistance of the transistor (between nodes A and B in the schematic) using Ohm's law, which relates the current passing through a thing to the voltage across a thing. The voltage across the transistor is shown on VM2, it's 4.7V. The current, which is the same all around the loop, measured by AM1, is about 230mA. Its equivalent resistance is then:

$$\begin{aligned}
R &= \frac{V}{I} \\ \\
&= \frac{4.7V}{230mA} \\ \\
&= 20\Omega
\end{aligned}$$

You could replace the transistor with a resistor of 20Ω, and the same current would flow. The same voltage would appear across the diodes, and the same voltage, 4.7V, would appear across the resistor. The transistor really is behaving just like a resistor.

Notice there are some volts across the LEDs, and some volts across the transistor, and that their sum must equal the supply voltage of 12V (in this example). In other words, the LEDs want the voltage that the LEDs want, and the transistor must "consume" the rest, so that the total is always 12V. That's Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL) for you.

The formula to calculate the power being dissipated by the transistor will be the product of the voltage across it, and current through it:

$$\begin{aligned}
P &= V \times I \\ \\
&= 4.7V \times 230mA \\ \\
&= 1W
\end{aligned}$$

All of that 1W is wasted as heat in the transistor, and is enough to make that transistor very hot, very quickly. Imagine if we were talking about 1A or more; power dissipation in the transistor can quickly become a problem. However, this "analogue control system" works. It has successfully established 230mA of current through the LEDs, and more importantly it has allowed the LEDs to choose whatever voltage they want for themselves.

LEDs don't really change their voltage much, even if current varies a lot, in this kind of arrangement, and the poor transistor has to "take up" whatever the LEDs don't, a more-or-less constant 5V here.

The problem is that the transistor is wasting power in this setup, and getting hot. It's inefficient and it may require cooling.

Now let's look at digital.

Digital control can keep the transistor cool, but to see why, we need to examine what current is flowing and what voltage is across the transistor in the two states, on and off.

When the transistor is completely off, like an infinite resistance, obviously no current is flowing; \$I=0\$. In that state, it cannot be dissipating any power, because \$P = V \times I = V \times 0 = 0\$.

If the transistor is fully switched on, it has near zero resistance, and the voltage across it must also be near-zero (let's say zero for the sake of argument). Remember Ohm's law \$V = I \times R = I \times 0 = 0\$. Now, if the voltage across the transistor is zero, then it can't be dissipating any power because \$P = V \times I = 0 \times I = 0\$. In other words, *in spite of there being current flowing*, there's no power dissipation in the transistor!

So, if we operate the transistor as a digital on/off switch, it never dissipates any power, and stays cool. How, then can we control the current? Well, we can't, but what we *can* do is switch the transistor on and off quickly, and control the ratio between on-time and off-time. In this way we achieve some *average* current somewhere between zero and whatever current flows when the transistor is kept completely on.

That ratio is called the "duty cycle", usually expressed as a percentage. If we wish to get maximum current, we use a duty cycle of 100%, meaning we never switch the transistor off. To extinguish the LEDs, we need a duty cycle of 0%, where the transistor is kept permanently off. If we want half-brightness, then a duty cycle of 50% is perfect, in which the transistor is off half the time, on for the rest.

This approach is called "pulse width modulation", PWM. The LEDs are switching on at maximum current for some time, then off at zero current for a while. They are flashing, but if we do the switching frequently enough, we don't see it. The *average* current is the product of duty cycle and maximum current, and the LED's apparent brightness is closely related to that average.

And the transistor stays cool.

To summarise so far:

If we use the transistor as a variable resistance, and control current through the LEDs that way, that's analogue control, also known as "linear regulation". It's easy, but the transistor can dissipate a lot of power.

If we employ PWM to switch the transistor on and off, alternating between full current and brightness and completely off, we can control *average* current by varying the PWM signal's duty cycle. That's digital control, in which the transistor dissipates (almost) no power, staying cool.

---

There are hybrid systems, too. That is, there's a linear (analogue) regulator, operating exactly as I described above, but it's switched off and on by a PWM signal! When the LEDs are lit, current is fixed by the transistor operating as an "active resistance", but when they are off, they are off. That means, you still have to consider the power dissipation in the pass transistor, but you get the controllability of PWM. Such a system is implemented by the [STCS1A](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stcs1a.pdf), which I wrote about in [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/554241/power-dissipation-of-mosfet-with-pwm-and-current-regulation/657832#657832).

---

To answer your last question, is it OK to use a resistive load instead of LEDs, in a constant current source, well, maybe not.

Earlier I mentioned that LEDs have a more-or-less constant forward voltage, even as current through them varies. This makes the remaining voltage dropped across the regulating transistor very stable and constant too. If your load is resistive, that assumption is no longer true, because the voltage across the resistor is directly proportional to the current through it.

If you can guarantee that the power dissipated in the regulating transistor is never excessive, I'll go out on a limb and say that constant current, analogue dimming, LED drivers will not complain about a resistive load. That's not a promise, just an educated guess. I'm wary to commit to a yes or no, because there are stability concerns in every linear system.

For PWM controlled regulators, I don't know. If, for example you have a resistive heating element, through which you want to control average current, off the top of my head I can't think why it wouldn't work, but I am wary of committing myself to an answer because every controller has its quirks.

---

The HV9919B you linked to combines PWM control with a third means of regulating current; "switch mode". It differs from both methods I have explained so far.

The IC uses an inductor as a store of energy, which is "topped up" periodically by briefly switching on the MOSFET. The nature of inductance is to try to keep current constant, even when the voltage across it changes. When the IC measures that the inductor current (which is also the same current passing through the LEDs) has fallen below some lower threshold, it momentarily switches on the MOSFET which has the effect of gently increasing (gently because the inductor inhibits sudden changes in current), until current reaches an upper threshold. Then it switches off again, and the process repeats.

The principle of operation is similar to a [relaxation oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_oscillator) using hysteresis, except rather than using a capacitor as the timing element, it uses an inductor, and rather than oscillating about some average voltage, it is current that rises and falls between the two thresholds.

This is extremely efficient, because the MOSFET is used as a switch, spending very little time in an intermediate partially conductive state where it dissipates power.

The PWM signal is not used to switch the LEDs off and on. Instead, the IC interprets the PWM signal as representing a "target" current. It calculates the two switching thresholds (hysteresis) based on the that duty cycle, but other than that the PWM signal has no role to play.

Unlike the digital control method I described above, the LEDs do not flash. Current through the LED ramps up and down between two very close threshold values, with an average value corresponding to the PWM input's duty cycle.

It's the best of PWM and switch-mode current regulation wrapped up in a single chip.

Comment: Thanks, this was really comprehensive. But it is possible for a current-controlling SMPS to adjust the current to the desired level, achieving efficient analog dimming right? It seems to be the same as your third "hybrid" option.

Answer (score 2):

LEDs are normally controlled by limiting the current.

The voltage across an LED doesn't change much as the current changes, so controlling an LED by adjusting the voltage doesn't really work.  You can go from LED off to LED burnt out very quickly.

Digital dimming involves setting the current through the LED to the highest level you want, then controlling the brightness using PWM.  That's switching the LED on and off very rapidly, faster than the eye can see.  The more time it's on, the brighter the LED looks.  The big advantage of digital dimming is that it can be controlled by one digital output pin of a microcontroller.

Analog dimming requires a variable current power supply.  Dimming the LED requires turning the current limit up and down.  It's less popular, since it's harder to control.  You need to generate an analog voltage, then convert that to an analog current through the LED.

If you want to control other loads, such as resistors, then you can.